# Get application stack API endpoint in Lambda handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Scenario is User's registeration Email verification

I am creating a lambda that will create a verification email and send to user - **Step 1**

On getting the email user will click on it and verify their email address - **Step 2**

**Problem** - While doing Step 1 how do I create the verification link's domain part I can hard code it directly in code but it looks incorrect? Is there any way I can pass it in SAM/Cloudformation Template itself or set any environment variable somewhere and can get access to it. I am using API Gateway in AWS to make it trigger approprate lambda function. Once user clicks the verification link it will trigger another lambda (given by - sso-email-verification path) in aws that will update the database and mark it as verified

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {



    let key = Math.random()

    await SSOGuest.create({
        email: email,
        status: 0,
        verification_key: key
    })

    let link = 'http://example.com/sso-email-verification?id='+key
    // < -- how to get http://example.com/ part dynamically 
    let params = {
        Destination: {  

            ToAddresses: [
                email
            ]
        },
        Message: { 
            Body: {  
                Text: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: `<p> Your verification link is ${link}</p>`
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                Data: 'Verification from team'
            }
        },
        Source: "support@example.sg",
        ReplyToAddresses: [

        ],
    };

    // Create the promise and SES service object
    var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' }).sendEmail(params).promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    sendPromise.then(function (data) {
        return result.sendSuccess({message:"success"});
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
        return result.sendServerError();
    });



})
```

Comment: If the lambda function is triggered via API gateway and your verification link shoud point to the same API gateway, you can simply check the `host` header ...

Comment: Yes that will do